# WordPress Font Resizer

Tags: wordpress

I have tried 2x plugins now on this site: http://projects4.yeahcan.com/oblmis/category/missions-news/mission-stories/
which will enable users to choose a smaller or larger font size. But it only seems to alter the text in the immediate vicinity.

If you scroll down to the top of the main white background section you will see three A's. A-, A- and A+. Please click these to see the effect.

Can anyone point out what I may be doing wrong or why it doesn't effect the rest of the page text. I know it may be a stab in the dark for you!

The plugin is set to affect text from the body tag down. Here is the plugin: http://inoplugs.com/projects/wordpress-font-resizer-plugin-inoplugs/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update: It only seems to alter any text that has **no** font-size specified. Weird!?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to change the font sizes from pixles to em's.